# Swift on array.sort - Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift

I am downgrading Swift code from Xcode 8.3.1 to Xcode 7.3.1.

The Swift compiler of Xcode 7.3.1 raises 
`Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`
while pointing on line `zeroParameterAndPaths.sort {`. The code was ok in Xcode 8.3.1.

What's wrong and how to fix it?

```
class NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath {
    let step : Int; // 0 = main, 1 = first outline, 2 = second outline
    let parameter : CGFloat;

    init(step: Int, parameter: CGFloat) {
        self.step = step;
        self.parameter = parameter;
    }
}



var zeroParameterAndPaths : [NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath] = [];

// ... some zeroParameterAndPaths .appendContentsOf calls

zeroParameterAndPaths.sort {
            return $0.parameter < $1.parameter
                    || ($0.parameter == $1.parameter
                    && ($0.step == 1 || ($0.step == 0 && $1.step == 2))
            )
        };
```

Comment: Still complains.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what your intended sort order is, but (unless I am mistaken), the closure returns `true` for *identical* arguments with `step=1`. That is not allowed. – (Unrelated to your current problem, but I just wanted to mention it)

Comment: @MartinR The compiler issue isn't the reason why people should avoid expressions like this xD

Comment: @MartinR Primary order is by the value of parameter. For the same parameter value the intended order is 1-0-2. The (parameter, step) is guaranteed to be unique. Don't worry about the meaning behind it. It has a meaning.

Comment: @alik: The sort predicate is required to be a strict weak ordering. In particular `a < a` must be false (Irreflexivity). That is not satisfied with your code.

Comment: @MartinR I've got it, thanks. So "$0.step == 1 && $1.step != 1" should fix it, right?

Comment: @alik: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. One is simply to do what the error message suggests, i.e. pulling the complex bool apart into separate pieces:

```
    zeroParameterAndPaths.sort {
        let bless = ($0.parameter < $1.parameter)
        let beq = ($0.parameter == $1.parameter)
        let band = ($0.step == 0 && $1.step == 2)
        let bor = ($0.step == 1 || band)
        let beqandbor = (beq && bor)
        return (bless || beqandbor)
    };
```

The other is to provide an explicit `in` line giving the param types and result type:

```
    zeroParameterAndPaths.sort {
        (a:NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath, b:NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath) -> Bool in
        return a.parameter < b.parameter
            || (a.parameter == b.parameter
                && (a.step == 1 || (a.step == 0 && b.step == 2))
        )
    };
```

Comment: Also, did you mean `sortInPlace`?

Comment: sort in Swift 3 ~ sortInPlace in Swift 2, so technically yes. But the second approach I chose does not work with sortInPlace (do not remember the error) so I have added "zero... =" to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make your class a little bit more helpful and make it implement the condition.  The compiler is much less likely to get confused in a function body than in a closure:

```
class NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath {
    let step : Int; // 0 = main, 1 = first outline, 2 = second outline
    let parameter : CGFloat;

    init(step: Int, parameter: CGFloat) {
        self.step = step;
        self.parameter = parameter;
    }

    func orderedBefore(_ other: NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath) -> Bool
    {
        return parameter <  other.parameter
            || parameter == other.parameter
               && (step == 1 || step == 0 && other.step == 2)
    }
}



var zeroParameterAndPaths : [NewConnectingSegmentZeroParameterAndPath] = [];

// ... some zeroParameterAndPaths .appendContentsOf calls

zeroParameterAndPaths.sort { $0.orderedBefore($1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue of the type inference engine not being able to quickly resolve such complex bool expressions, such expressions are really hard to follow. I suggest you break it down into something simpler, like so:

```
zeroParameterAndPaths.sort {
    if $0.parameter != $1.parameter { return $0.parameter < $1.parameter ]
    if $0.step == 1 { return true }
    if $0.step == 0 && $1.step == 2 { return true }
    return false
};
```

There's my attempt at it. I'm not even sure if it's correct, the original expression is pretty hard to follow.